# How to combine data from two different models to be shown in one selection in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a library app in which one person can borrow a book either teacher or student in one borrow. In my borrow form both the model have their selection I want only one selection for both and control that through another virtual selection which has two options teacher and student by selecting one of them it dynamically loads the data form one table.

```
  <%= form_for(@borrow) do |f| %>
  <% if @borrow.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@borrow.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this borrow from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @borrow.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :book_issue_date %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :book_issue_date %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :book_return_date %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :book_return_date %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :book_id %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select(:book_id, Book.all, :id, :book_title) %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :student_id %><br>
     <%= f.collection_select(:student_id, Student.all, :id, :student_name) %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :teacher_id %><br>
   <%= f.collection_select(:teacher_id, Teacher.all, :id, :teacher_name) %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

[screen shot of borrow new page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zeffv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use polymorphic relationship as follow

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :borrowable, polymorphic: true
end 

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books, as: :borrowable
end

class Students < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books, as: :borrowable
end
```

Now you you have single selection on book

```
@book.borrowable_type
```

will give you Teacher or Student, you can have other attributes in book i.e. book_issue_date, book_return_date etc

Comment: What customization I have to do in borrow form.

Comment: @MuhammadRafique you have to change model association in book, teacher and students according to i explained above

Comment: Ok, but the form for borrow also needs to be changes according to the new associations. I am asking about the changes that need in the Borrow form. Right now in borrow form both Student and Teacher have their collection select.